# Retrieve Request Payload from Post Request

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

So I made a JavaScript Post Request with ajax (axios) which looks like this:

```
axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'placeholder-url',
        data: {
            test1: 'test',
            test2: 3
        }
    }).then(response => (console.log(response)));
```

Which correctly fills the Request Payload:

[image: Request Payload]

The Request definitely Arrives correctly, because I can receive a response and i can successfully send Query Parameters in the Url, however i can't read the request payload.

$_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST, $this->arguments, $this->request do not contain them and `file_get_contents('php://input')` is empty.

Here's my TypoScript Configuration:

```
ajax = PAGE
ajax {
    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        //additionalHeaders = Content-type:application/json
        xhtml_cleaning = 0
        admPanel = 0
        debug = 0
        no_cache = 1
    }
    typeNum = 1000
    10 < tt_content.list.20.ext_action
}
```

How can i retrieve the content of the Request Payload?

Comment: What happens, if you access your page with the output directly in the browser? Is there an error displayed? BTW: If this is your own extension and you need to get json objects in your axios request, you can also use the TYPO3 JsonView (\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\View\JsonView) for direct output. In my opinion the better way if you are working with your own extension / records, as you don't need that TS-Overhead.

Comment: No there's no error, Status Code is 200, but thank you anyways. It seem like when I output the content with debug and exit it is empty. It is however sent with a return. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I use an ActionController that needs direct access to GET/POST-Parameters, I use

```
TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GP('parameterName')
```

Do not bother inspecting $_GET or $POST, but let the framework do the work for you (More info on [_GP()](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/7.6/en-us/ApiOverview/MainClasses/HighPriorityFunctions/Index.html)).